# Minipage not centered in frame

Tags: beamer, positioning

I'm making a presentation, and I have a lot of graphs and text.

In one specific frame, I'm using the `\only` command to separate the graphs and the text. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Método B}
\begin{figure}[h]
\only<1>{\centering{\Ovalbox{\resizebox{0.8\paperwidth}{!}{\input{1b}}}}}
\only<2>{\centering{\Ovalbox{\resizebox{0.8\paperwidth}{!}{\input{2b}}}}}
\end{figure}
\only<3>{
\shadowbox{
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.9\paperwidth}
Temos que
\[ \frac{\delta}{\lambda}=\frac{\phi\lambda}{2\pi\lambda}=B\cdot l\cdot E^2=B\cdot l\cdot\frac{V^2}{d^2} \]
logo
\[ \phi(V^2) = \frac{2\pi Bl}{d^2}\cdot V^2\]
O coeficiente angular da reta que melhor se ajustou aos dados é $5.66\cdot 10^{-6}$ V$^{-2}$. As dimensões $l$ e $d$ da célula Kerr são
$l=20.08$ mm e $d\approx 1$ mm. Com isso temos que
\[ B = \frac{d^2}{2\pi l}\cdot 5.66\cdot 10^{-6} = 55\]
\end{minipage}
}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I wanted the box with the `\only<3>` part to be centered at the frame, but this is what I get:
[image: \only<1>]

[image: \only<2>]

[image: \only<3>]

Visually the `\only<3>` part is not centered (look at the position of the box: it is at the bottom).
I already tried lots of combinations of the center environment, but none of them
made any difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you don't need the `figure` environment in Beamer:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Método B}
% \begin{figure}[h]   %commented here
\only<1>{\centering\Ovalbox{\resizebox{0.8\paperwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{1b}}}}
\only<2>{\centering\Ovalbox{\resizebox{0.8\paperwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{2b}}}}
% \end{figure}       %commented here
\only<3>{
    \shadowbox{
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\paperwidth}
            Temos que
            \[ \frac{\delta}{\lambda}=\frac{\phi\lambda}{2\pi\lambda}=B\cdot l\cdot E^2=B\cdot l\cdot\frac{V^2}{d^2} \]
            logo
            \[ \phi(V^2) = \frac{2\pi Bl}{d^2}\cdot V^2\]
            O coeficiente angular da reta que melhor se ajustou aos dados é $5.66\cdot 10^{-6}$ V$^{-2}$. As dimensões $l$ e $d$ da célula Kerr são
            $l=20.08$ mm e $d\approx 1$ mm. Com isso temos que
            \[ B = \frac{d^2}{2\pi l}\cdot 5.66\cdot 10^{-6} = 55\]
        \end{minipage}
    }
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which produced this:

[image]

Now if you want more space between the Title and the box, just add some `skip` inside your `\only<3>`. With a `\bigskip` you get:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that worked! Muitíssimo obrigado (thank you very much in portuguese)! But why the figure environment causes this?

Comment: @Larara because by default `figure` does reserve some vertical space, and since it was not into an `only` macro, that space was reserved in all the slides. You can test this by restoring you `figure` but placing it inside another `only` macro, you'll see that the result is the same as removing `figure` because now the space is reserved inside `only`. However, since `figure` is a floating environment you don't really need it in beamer. So, long story short, just remove it :)